# Does any one know exactly what's the utility of this line code " r.exec("C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/c5.0 -f C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/see5/rating") "

Tags: java, runtime.exec

This is the line code :

```
r.exec("C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/c5.0 -f C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/see5/rating");
```

The problem is that I didn't understand the meaning cause I forked the project and I have to change it so to fit my needs. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: A project with no name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, r represents runtime object

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

which is calling process `exec()` method with a system command specified.

[C5.0](https://www.rulequest.com/see5-unix.html) is a RuleQuest Research Data Mining Tool.

Format to call c5.0 is :

```
c5.0 -f <filestem> [options]
```

This invokes C5.0 with the -f option that identifies the application name

So **C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/see5/rating** should be application name.

Answer (score 2):

It says "I'm not going to do things in Java anymore, and instead run the command line program called `c5.0`."

Specifically it expects there to be an executable program on your filesystem at "C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/c5.0", and that program also takes some input also on your filesystem at "C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/see5/rating".

A google search suggests C5.0 may be a [data mining routine](https://www.rulequest.com/see5-unix.html) called RuleQuest(?).

Comment: It's a little bit more clear. I'm going to see the link proposed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's invoking an external program

```
C:/Users/May/Desktop/test/c5.0
```

You need to find out what that is.